# Electric Potential Line Integral: Two Methods and Two Different Results

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the following line integral
$$-\int\vec E \cdot d\vec l$$
With $\vec E=\dfrac{1}{r^2}\, \hat r$ (radial electric field) and $d\vec l=dr \,\hat r$.

**Definitions:**
[image]
                                              <sub>(Image Source: Introduction to Electrodynamics 4th - David J. Griffiths)</sub>

$$\left. \mbox{$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\vec r &\equiv x\hat i+y \hat j + z\hat k
\\
\\r&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
\end{alignat}
$}\right\}
\implies \hat r=\frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}}
$$

- $\vec r$ is the position vector
- $r$ is the magnitude of position vector
- $\hat r$ is a unit vector pointing radially outward

---

### Method 1:

$$-\int\vec E \cdot d\vec l=-\int\frac{1}{r^2}\,dr\,(\hat r \cdot \hat r)=-\int \frac{1}{r^2}\,dr= \color{green}{\frac{1}{r}}$$

---

### Method 2:

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
-\int\vec E \cdot d\vec l &= -\int \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}} \cdot (dx\, \hat i +dy\, \hat j + dz\, \hat k)
\\[2px] &= -\int \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,(x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz)
\\[2px] &= -\int \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,dx -\int \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,dy -\int \frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,dz
\\[2px] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
\\[2px] &= \frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \color{red}{\frac 3 r}
\end{alignat}
$$

---

The second method gave the wrong result. My question is: what is my conceptual mistake here and how can I make the second method work?

Comment: Cartesian $d\vec{l}$ is always $(dx, dy, dz)$, no exceptions.

Comment: I guess the flaw is in the $(dx\hat{i}+dy\hat j+dz\hat k)$ part. When you move incremental lengths in all the three directions, you integrate over a volume.

Comment: @learner But then, how do I write $d\vec l$ for the 2nd method?

Comment: I think your flaw is is conceptual. Could you tell me how you would compute $$\int yzdx+xzdy+xydz$$

Comment: You can't just say $$\int yzdx+xzdy+xydz=\int yzdx + \int xzdz +\int xydz=xyz+xyz+xyz=3xyz$$ because you'd be getting the wrong primitive... You need to find the scalar$-$valued function $f(x,y,z)$ whose gradient equals $\big<yz,xz,xy\big>$ which we know will exist since the vector field $$(x,y,z) \rightarrow \big<yz,xz,xy\big>$$ is irrotational.

Comment: In your first solution, you said that $-\int \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ which is correct since $$\vec{\nabla}\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Bigg)=\Bigg<\frac{-x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}},\frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}},\frac{-z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\Bigg>$$

Comment: @MatthewHolder So, in your example:

$$
\frac{d\varphi}{dx}=yz \implies \varphi(x,y,z) =xyz + C(y,z)
\\\frac{d\varphi}{dy}=xz=xz+C'(y,z) \implies \varphi(x,y,z) = xyz +C(z)
\\\frac{d\varphi}{dz}=xy=xy+C'(z) \implies \varphi(x,y,z) = xyz + k, k \in \mathbb{R}
$$

I think I understood, thanks!

Comment: So, if the problem was not in $d\vec l=dx \,\hat i + dy \,\hat j + dz\, \hat k $, what is the path to prove that $dr\,\hat r=dx \,\hat i + dy \,\hat j + dz\, \hat k $ and to find $dr$ in terms of $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$?

Comment: You got the correct primitive! Great! If $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\text{ }$ is the magnitude of the position vector, then $$\hat{r}=\Bigg<\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Bigg>=\bigg<\frac{x}{r},\frac{y}{r},\frac{z}{r}\bigg>$$
which means $r \hat{r}=\vec{r}$. If you want to express $dr$ in terms of $dx,dy,$ and $dz$ we can take total derivatives: $$dr=r_xdx+r_ydy+r_zdz=\Bigg<\frac{x}{r},\frac{y}{r},\frac{z}{r}\Bigg>\cdot \bigg<dx,dy,dz\bigg>=\hat{r}\cdot d\vec{r}$$ From this we can say $rdr=\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r}$

Comment: I think I understood what you have done above, but what I don't understand is why the $d\vec l$s for both methods aren't equivalent (in other words, why $\left<dx,dy,dz \right> =d \vec r \neq dr \, \hat r$ ?)

$$
dr\, \hat r= \\ \bigg<\frac{x^2}{r^2}dx+\frac{xy}{r^2}dy+\frac{xz}{r^2}dz,\frac{xy}{r^2}dx+\frac{y^2}{r^2}dy+\frac{yz}{r^2}dz,\frac{xz}{r^2}dx+\frac{yz}{r^2}dy+\frac{z^2}{r^2}dz\bigg>
$$

(I tried, but couldn't get $\left< dx,dy,dz\right>$ from $dr \, \hat r$ ).

Comment: @MatthewHolder Using $rdr=\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r}$, I get the expected result:
$$
\vec E \cdot d \vec l =\vec E \cdot d \vec r=\frac{1}{r^2}\hat r\cdot d\vec r =\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\color{blue}{\vec r}}{r}\color{blue}{\cdot d\vec r}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\color{blue}{r \, dr}}{r}=\frac{1}{r^2}dr
$$
But in every place and book I looked, they write $d\vec r = dr\, \hat r$. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @MatthewHolder So, what am I missing here? I'm trying, but I really can't understand.

Comment: Is your book saying $d\vec{r}=dr\text{ } \hat{r}$ or are they saying $d\vec{l}=dr\text{ } \hat{r}$? Obviously we have $d\vec{r}\neq dr\text{ } \hat{r}$ so maybe you're book is **defining** $d\vec{l}$ to be $dr\text{ } \hat{r}$. I don't see why they would call $\big<dx,dy,dz\big>$ to be $d\vec{l}$ when they could just call this vector $d\vec{r}$. That's the best explanation I can give you.

Comment: @MatthewHolder You have made me realize something: here we are working entirely on the cartesian coordinate system. When someone writes $d\vec r = dr\,\hat r$ (or $d\vec l = dr\,\hat r\,$) , this expression refers to spherical coordinates. So maybe my confusion is in the notation.

Comment: I think that when I solved via the first method, I used spherical coordinates, thinking (wrongly) that I was working with cartesian coordinates.

So, the right way to solve using the position vector $r$ in cartesian coordinates is not the way did in the question, but the way you taught me: using $rdr=\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r}$

Comment: @MatthewHolder Thanks for your help! If you put your comments in an answer I'll certainly upvote and choose it as the best answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113098/discussion-between-matthew-holder-and-vinicius-acp).